# How to search for version number from given text in python:

Tags: python, regex

How to search for version no python:

```
Build Host   : iox-lux-013 
Version      : 3.2.8.08I sample
```

I tried:

```
import re
p=re.compile("Version.*: (.*?) ")
list=p.findall(s)
for i in list:
        print i
```

works good
but not for:

```
Version      : 3.2.8.08I
```

doesnt work :/

Comment: [Works on my machine](http://ideone.com/5tQKFl) just fine. Show us your whole code. Where is `s` defined?

Answer (score 1):

Use `\S+` to match one or more non-space characters.

```
p = re.compile(r"Version\s*:\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)*[A-Z]\b)")
```

`\s*` matches zero or more spaces , so you don't need to use `.*` before `:`

**Example:**

```
>>> s = '''Build Host   : iox-lux-013 
Version      : 3.2.8.08I sample
Version      : 3.2.8.08I'''
re.findall(r"Version\s*:\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)*[A-Z]\b)", s)
['3.2.8.08I', '3.2.8.08I']
```

Comment: Hi, If i give like this  "Version      : 3:2:8:08I ''' also it is extracting

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

s = '''Build Host   : iox-lux-013
Version      : 3.2.8.08I sample
Version      : 3.2.8.08I '''

 f =  re.findall(r"Version\s+:( [0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+[A-Z])(\s[A-Z])*", s)

print(f)
```

Use \S+ to match one or more non-space characters.

`( [0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+[A-Z])` 
this group will check for the version numbering. `(\s[A-Z])*` will check whether the string + space is availabl;e or not

`*`  -> 0 or more

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).